# Kubernetes: 2 PVCs in 2 namespaces binding to the same PV, one successful, one failed

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

So I have 2 PVCs in 2 namespaces binding to 1 PV:

The following are the PVCs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-git
  namespace: mlo-dev
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: mlo-git
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-git
  namespace: mlo-stage
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: mlo-git
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

and the PV:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv-git
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: mlo-git
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /git
```

in the namespace "mlo-dev", the binding is successful:

```
$ kubectl describe pvc pvc-git -n mlo-dev
Name:          pvc-git
Namespace:     mlo-dev
StorageClass:  mlo-git
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pv-git
Labels:        type=local
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      1Gi
Access Modes:  RWX
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    
...
various different pods here...
...
Events:        <none>
```

Whereas in the namespace "mlo-stage", the binding is failed with the error message: storageclass.storage.k8s.io "mlo-git" not found

```
$ kubectl describe pvc pvc-git -n mlo-stage
Name:          pvc-git
Namespace:     mlo-stage
StorageClass:  mlo-git
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        type=local
Annotations:   Finalizers:  [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By: 
...
various different pods here...
...
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                   From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                  ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  3m4s (x302 over 78m)  persistentvolume-controller  storageclass.storage.k8s.io "mlo-git" not found
```

As I know, PV is not scoped to namespace, so it should be possible for PVCs in different namespaces to bind to the same PV?

+++++
Added:
+++++

when "kubectl describe pv pv-git", I got the following:

```
$ kubectl describe pv pv-git
Name:            pv-git
Labels:          type=local
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    mlo-git
Status:          Bound
Claim:           mlo-dev/pvc-git
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWX
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        1Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /git
    HostPathType:  
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Can you `kubectl describe` the PV as well?

Comment: Thank you @Jonas, I have added the results of "kubectl describe pv pv-git"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduced your scenario (however if you would provide your `storageclass` yaml to exact reproduction, and changed `AccessMode` for tests) and in my opinion this behavior is correctly (worked as designed).

When you want to check if specific object is `namespaced` you can use command:

```
$ kubectl api-resources | grep pv
persistentvolumeclaims            pvc                                         true         PersistentVolumeClaim
persistentvolumes                 pv                                          false        PersistentVolume
```

As `PVC` is true its mean `pvc` is namespaced, and `PV` is not.

[PersistentVolumeClain](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) and [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) are bounding in relationship 1:1. When your first PVC bounded to PV, this PV is `taken` and cannot be used again in that moment. **You should create second `PV`.** It can be changed depends on `reclaimPolicy` and what happend with `pop`/`deployment`

I guess you are using [Static](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#static) provisioning.

> A cluster administrator creates a number of PVs. They carry the details of the real storage, which is available for use by cluster users. They exist in the Kubernetes API and are available for consumption.

In this case you have to create 1 `PV` to 1 `PVC`.

If you would use cloud environment, you would use [Dynamic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic) provisioning.

> When none of the static PVs the administrator created match a user's PersistentVolumeClaim, the cluster may try to dynamically provision a volume specially for the PVC. This provisioning is based on StorageClasses: the PVC must request a storage class and the administrator must have created and configured that class for dynamic provisioning to occur.

As for example, on [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) I've tried to reproduce it and 1 `PVC` bound to `PV`. As GKE is using `Dynamic provisioning`, when you defined only `PVC` it used `default storageclass` and automatically created `PV`.

```
$ kubectl get pv,pvc -A
NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM               STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pv-git                                     1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    mlo-dev/pvc-git     mlo-git                 15s
persistentvolume/pvc-e7a1e950-396b-40f6-b8d1-8dffc9a304d0   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    mlo-stage/pvc-git   mlo-git                 6s

NAMESPACE   NAME                            STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mlo-dev     persistentvolumeclaim/pvc-git   Bound    pv-git                                     1Gi        RWO            mlo-git        10s
mlo-stage   persistentvolumeclaim/pvc-git   Bound    pvc-e7a1e950-396b-40f6-b8d1-8dffc9a304d0   1Gi        RWO            mlo-git        9s
```

**Solution**

To fix this issue, you should create another `PersistentVolume` to bound second `PVC`.

**For more details** about bounding you can check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839938/kubernetes-pvcs-sharing-a-single-pv). If you would like more information about `PVC` check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412552/why-readwriteonce-is-working-on-different-nodes).

**If second `PV` won't help**, please provide more details about your environment (Minikube/Kubeadm, K8s version, OS, etc.) and your `storageclass` YAML.

Comment: Thank you @PjoterS, your solution of creating another PV to bound to the 2nd PVC fixes my problem! The answer is very informative!